# RDLC Keep Together and Record placement

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I have a report that I'm having a bit of an issue with. The `keep together` appears to work sometimes, and not at others. On top of that, due to the attempt at the separation of records in the report, the alignment is off. Here's the `rdlc` inside visual studio:

[image]

Here's page 1:

[image]

Page 1 looks fine. I'm just showing this as a reference. Page 2:

[image]

Now, with page 2, you can see that the pink header bar is right underneath the pink line, which is exactly how it should be. But looking at page 3:

[image]

You can see several things happening here. 1.) The record starts far below the pink line. 2.) At the bottom, you can see that the whole record is not on the page. The rest of it is on page 4 (this is the most important issue). Now, I've turned `keep together` set to `true` for just about every single thing in the `rdlc` that I could think of, yet it's still separating on some records. What I've got set up is that the record is a `table`(with a `grouping` that has `keep together` set to true, the table itself has `keep together` set to `true`, and the table is the child of a `rectangle` which has `keep together` set to `true` as well. This is my first time working with `rdlc` reports, and I fear I may be either overthinking this, or just missing something silly. But, how can I ensure the `keep together` works properly, and how can I ensure that the record starts in the appropriate location?

Comment: images dont show anything on my screen

Comment: @BWoods: Not sure what to tell you on that one. I used SO's built in image uploader.

Comment: Is your output from a Visual Studio Preview?  These are often inaccurate.

Comment: @MikeHoney: yes, the top screen is from visual studio. I posted it to show how the grouping should be.

Comment: I'm asking about the output i.e. Page 1, 2 & 3.  Are they rendered as a Preview in Visual Studio?

Comment: @MikeHoney: Oh, sorry. No, that is in the browser (Chrome, IE, Firefox, and Safari).